# Problema para representar JSON en Genexus

Tags: json, genexus, genexus15

Nos encontramos usando [HL7 FHIR](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/) y tenemos problemas al intentar representar ciertas estructuras en SDT de Genexus. Los [recursos FHIR](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/resourcelist.html) son estructuras JSON. Cada recurso FHIR logramos representarlo en una SDT Genexus.
Cualquiera de estos recursos, puede contener una propiedad **contained** dentro del JSON. Esta propiedad contained es una colección de otros recursos, puede venir cualquier recurso dentro de ella.

Necesito generar la siguiente estructura en un SDT GeneXus:

```
    {
      "resourceType": "RequestGroup",
      "id": "example",
    
      "contained": [
        {
          "resourceType": "MedicationRequest",
          "id": "medicationrequest-1",
          "status": "unknown",
          "intent": "proposal",
          "medicationCodeableConcept": {
            "text": "Medication 1"
          },
          "subject": {
            "reference": "Patient/example"
          }
        },
        {
          "resourceType": "Patient",
          "id": "example",
          "active": true,
          "name": [
            {
              "use": "official",
              "family": "Chalmers",
              "given": [
                "Peter",
                "James"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "gender": "male",
          "birthDate": "1974-12-25"
        }
      ],
    
      "status": "draft",
      "intent": "plan",
      "priority": "routine",
      "note": [
        {
          "text": "Additional notes about the request group"
        }
      ]
      
    }
```

En este ejemplo, contained contiene un recurso *Patient* y un recurso *MedicationRequest*. Estos recursos están mapeados en sus respectivos SDT en GeneXus.

Tengo problemas al representar la propiedad contained en un SDT Genexus, la cual puede contener una colección de JSON/SDT de diferente tipo dentro de ella. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para mapear contained en un **SDT** Genexus para que al hacer **toJson()** obtenga la estructura anterior?

**Intentos Realizados**

No puedo usar la herramienta *Application Integration -> JSON Import*.

Porque el resultado no es el esperado. Cada posible tipo dentro de contained (Patient, MedicationRequest, etc) ya están mapeados en sus respectivos SDT y es necesario reutilizarlos.

No puedo hacer esto:

[image: No se puede definir de un tipo genérico como Properties o similar]

Porque un item de contained no es una colección solo del tipo Patient, puede incluír de cualquier recurso FHIR (MedicationRequest, Encounter, Observation, etc).

No puedo hacer esto:

[image: Agrega etiquetas no deseadas al hacer toJson]

Porque al hacer **toJson()** genera las etiquetas “MedicationRequest” y “Patient”. Ver la siguiente imagen: del lado izquierdo la estructura deseada, del lado derecho la generada por Genexus toJson(). Esas etiquetas hacen inválido el JSON a utilizar.
[image: Comparación estructura deseada vs Genexus]

No puedo hacer hacer esto:

[image: contained tipo varchar]

Ni esto:

[image: contained tipo varchar collection]

Porque, al ser un LongVarChar y hacer **toJson()**, GeneXus encierra entre comillas dobles (“) el valor de contained y agrega caracteres para escapar las comillas dobles de las propiedades dentro de contained.

```
    "contained":"[
    {
    \"resourceType\":\"MedicationRequest\",
    \"id\":\"81-158-185066-4177\",
    \"status\":\"active\",
    \"intent\":\"order\",
```

Estos caracteres hacen inválida la estructura.

Por lo visto, la estructura para representarlo en Genexus y que luego de hacer toJson() quede como en el ejemplo inicial deseado, sería:
[image: posibilidad no existente en Genexus 1]

O tal vez de esta manera:
[image: posibilidad no existente en Genexus 2]

Pero estas alternativas no son posible de crear en GeneXus. No se pueden colocar 2 items en un collection ni etiquetas sin nombre.

¿Cómo puede entonces representarse la estructura contained en un SDT de Genexus, para que al hacer toJson se genere la estructura deseada?

```
  "contained": [
    {
      "resourceType": "MedicationRequest",
      "id": "medicationrequest-1",
      "status": "unknown",
      "intent": "proposal",
      "medicationCodeableConcept": {
        "text": "Medication 1"
      },
      "subject": {
        "reference": "Patient/example"
      }
    },
    {
      "resourceType": "Patient",
      "id": "example",
      "active": true,
      "name": [
        {
          "use": "official",
          "family": "Chalmers",
          "given": [
            "Peter",
            "James"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "gender": "male",
      "birthDate": "1974-12-25"
    }
  ]
```

Versión en uso: Genexus 16 upgrade 10.

Comment: Creo que el caso que planteas puede manejarse tal como explica aquí https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?37750,Consuming+JSON+with+GeneXus+Properties+Data+Type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respuesta del soporte de Genexus: actualmente no se puede evitar que al serializar una colección, en el json resultante se incluya el nombre de las colecciones (ej: “MedicationRequest” del caso mencionado).
Eso solo es posible usando el SDT en los parámetros de los métodos de un API Object.

Soporte indica que está en planes de agregarse a futuro, pero actualmente no se puede.
https://www.genexus.com/es/developers/websac?data=49741

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizar lo siguiente, creando el sdt en forma manual, o parte.

Con imágenes se entiende mejor, pero un campo su tipo de dato puede ser una estructura

MedicationRequest  sdt

[image: MedicationRequest sdt]

Patient sdt

[image: Patient sdt]

contained sdt

[image: contained sdt]

Finalmente la estructura principal,

RequestGroup sdt

[image: RequestGroup]

La estructura anterior se ve de la siguiente forma

[image: estructura]

Comment: Muestra la estructura _como texto, con formato_, ya que no todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Gracias @Iza por tu respuesta. Lamentablemente es similar al caso de la derecha de la imagen con fondo verde: Genexus genera la etiqueta con el nombre "MedicationRequest" (o Patient) y esto es lo que se busca omitir. 
Debería quedar de esta manera:

"contained": [
    {
      "resourceType": "MedicationRequest",
      "id": "medicationrequest-1",
      "status": "unknown",
      "intent": "proposal",
      "medicationCodeableConcept": {
        "text": "Medication 1"
      },
      "subject": {
        "reference": "Patient/example"
      }
    }

Comment: Quizá te pueda servir esto? No lo utilice nunca, pero recuerdo que habla de tu caso... Estructuras variables...   https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?37750,Consuming+JSON+with+GeneXus+Properties+Data+Type

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).